# accessing title attribute in codebehind(C#)

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a textbox

```
<ASP:TextBox runat="server" id="txtFirstName" title="First Name"> </ASP:TextBox>
<ASP:TextBox runat="server" id="txtLastName" title="Last Name"> </ASP:TextBox>
```

I use Jquery Labelify plugin to show the title text inside the textbox.

Now in code behind i want to add "*" to title text depending up on the settings present in the DB.

So i have to know how i will be able to retrieve/set title attribute of TextBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write `txtFirstName.Attributes["title"] = whatever`.

Comment: string text=txtFirstName.Attributes["title"]; will this work to retrieve it?